# getting wrong anwers on spoj AP2

Tags: c++, optimization

I was solving a question [SPOJ AP2](https://www.spoj.com/problems/AP2/)

You will be given the 3rd term , 3rd last term and the sum of the series. You need print length of the series & the series.

Logic used -> first term+last term=third term + third last term

```
sum=n/2(first+last)
```

I tried many test cases I am getting correct output in all  of them
But On spoj  I am getting wrong answer  "WA"

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
        int t;
        cin>>t;
        while(t--){
            long long int third;
            long long int thirdlast;
            long long int sum;
            cin>>third>>thirdlast>>sum;
            long long int n=(2*sum)/(third+thirdlast);
            long long int d= (thirdlast-third)/(n-5);  //(2*thirdlast-third*n+3*third)/(5-n);
            long long int a=(third-2*d);
            //cout<<n<<endl;
            //cout<<d<<endl;
            //int d=0;
            for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
                long long int temp=d*(i-1);
              //  int t=a+d;
                cout<<a+temp<<" ";


            }
            cout<<endl;

        }
    }
```

Comment: You are printing an extra space at the end of your line. Is the judging platform robust to that?

Answer (score 0):

You may have overflow at this line:

```
n=(2*sum)/(third + thirdlast);
```

You can avoid overflow in this way :

```
n = 2 * (sum/(third + thirdlast));
```

However, as `third + thirdlast`may not divide `sum`, you have to test it and add `n++`if necessary.

Another solution is to use `unsigned long long` for `n`